# Use Ajax to load/unload modal windows with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap (Version 2.3.1) and I'm using Ajax to load in a modal window. Is there a way to remove the modal window from the DOM when I close the modal window?

```
$('[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
         $(url).modal('open');
        } else {
            $.get(url, function(data) {
                $(data).modal();
            }).success(function() {
                console.log('success');

                // I tried this below but didn't work
                // $('#modalClose).on('click',function(){
                //    $('#myModalWindow').remove();
                // });
            });
        }
    });
```

My button:

```
<a href="path/to/modal.html" data-target="#" data-toggle="modal">Launch modal</a>
```

In my modal window, I have a close button.

```
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
```

However, when I close the modal, the html is still in the DOM and if I load the modal again, it outputs the HTML again. Is there a way to remove the modal window from the DOM when I close the modal window?

Comment: Have you found a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Additional css classes associated with a Bootstrap modal need to be removed.

Try putting this in success:

```
$('body').on('click', '#btn-close-modal', function () {
    $('#my-modal').modal('hide');
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
});
```

Where `btn-close-modal` is some button you use to remove the modal and `my-modal` is the name of the modal in question.

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty straightforward using [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/):

```
<button id="ModalClose" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>

$('#ModalClose').on('click',function(){
    $('#IdOfModal').remove();
});
```

This should remove the full modal HTML from the DOM. Just note I gave the close button an id, and use that id as click reference.

If your modal (and therefore close button) is loaded through AJAX, then the dynamically-loaded elements will only be able to have any Javascript/jQuery work with them if applied in a callback function for that modal's load.

Comment: I tried this, but nothing happens when I click the #ModalClose. I even tried putting a console.log('close modal') in the click function but no luck.

Comment: the modal is loaded in through AJAX right? because you will need to apply this logic in a callback function if so. answer edited to reflect this.

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you mean put the close function in the 'success' callback? If so, I tried and it's not working. See my edit to see what I did.

Comment: is this modal HTML statically in the page? or is it dynamically loaded from somewhere else using a `.load()` function or something?

Comment: The modal window html is not on the page at first. When I click "Launch Modal" I use .get to load the file "modals.html".

Comment: okay the callback function is not `.success()`, its the function where you plug the data in with `$(data).modal()`. try plugging the click function in there.